# Stop PWC6117 errors from jasper JspServlet?

Tags: java, jsp, jetty

For my spring webapp, I keep all my JSP files inside WEB-INF to make sure people cannot directly gain access to them through the browser.

If someone tries to access a jsp file directly (eg. http://myapp.com/index.jsp), they get a 404 error which is correct.  However, I get the following error in my logs:

```
SEVERE: PWC6117: File "/myapp/webapp/index.jsp" not found
```

I don't want this logged, as I have no interest in someone getting a 404 if they looked for a JSP file - they shouldn't find it.  But this error message means my logs are getting filled of "SEVERE" errors.  Is there any way to stop this logging, or get jasper to completely ignore JSP requests coming from the client?

I'm using jetty 7.x

Thanks!